# Multiple Input Properties vs. Single Input Property

Tags: angular

Having a debate as to whether it is "better" to define normalised properties for a new Angular components or supply a single property that encapsulates said properties.

### Normalised Option

Three inputs - one for the xAxis, one for the yAxis and one for options.

```
[
   { "id": "1", "label": "Dave" },
   { "id": "2", "label": "Laura" }
]
```

```
[
   { "id": "1", "label": "Happy" },
   { "id": "2", "label": "Sad" }
]
```

```
{
   "maxRowSelections": "1",
   "lockRowOnMaxSelections": "false"
}
```

### Encapsulated Option

One input.

```
{
   "xAxis": [
      { "id": "1", "label": "Dave" },
      { "id": "2", "label": "Laura" }
   ],
   "yAxis": [
      { "id": "1", "label": "Happy" },
      { "id": "2", "label": "Sad" }
   ],
   "options": {
      "maxRowSelections": "1",
      "lockRowOnMaxSelections": "false"
   }
}
```

I personally favour the normalised approach. I think it is clearer and therefore easier to maintain. I think it also makes listening for changes in the inputs simpler. Both of these arguments feel a bit subjective.

The other guy favours the encapsulated option and argues this is how a lot of libraries available online do it. We also need to load components dynamically and having a single Input property named the same on all of our components definitely makes that requirement much easier to achieve with our existing knowledge; no argument from me there.

I'm wondering if anyone can put forward more informed arguments to favour one approach over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters so much. Do what comes in handy for your work. If data does belong together and are not optional, like x and y asis or options, I would do one input - simply to make the HTML more readable. But if I have optional inputs or data that has nothing to do with each other, I usually make many inputs. However: I don't see a real benefit from one or the other.